# How do I determine if a HTTP request came from a browser or some agent

Tags: asp.net-web-api, httprequest

I would like to know what is the best practice for distinguishing between a request that was made from a browser, or some agent (Like postman for example, but also scripting tools).
This is not for security measures, only different logic that should be applied, per the use case.

I am using the following approach:

```cs
HttpBrowserCapabilities browserCapabilities = context.Request.Browser;

if (browserCapabilities.Browser == "Unknown" && browserCapabilities.Id == "default")
```

Which is working for me.

However, i wanted to hear your feedback on this method, and if you think that things can go wrong with this approach.
I did not find any reference on Web to this approach, so i wonder what am i missing.
Is it reliable or not ?

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

The User Agent is the normal mechanism for this. Look at `context.Request.Headers.UserAgent`. And yes, some scripting tools will lie and pretend to be browsers. But if this really isn't about security, that's on them.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback,
I am aware of the user agent method, and aware that The UA string contains details about the browser type, rendering engine, and operating system,
But i was not able to determine how to query the UA to indicate it's defiantly not a browser,
If you have such method (Regex) i would love to learn,
Thank you

Comment: @Gargml you could use something like this?https://jonlabelle.com/snippets/view/yaml/browser-user-agent-regular-expressions

Comment: @Gargml Unfortunately, one could write an entire book about parsing the User Agent. But it's what we have.